# How do I store a string in an multidimensional array in C?

Tags: c

I feel silly for asking, but I had trouble finding my answer. How do I re-assign "Rose" to "Douglas"? It seems like I have to use a loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  char arr[3][12]= { "Rose", "India", "technologies" };
  printf("Array of String is = %s,%s,%s\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
  arr[0][0] = {"Douglas"};
  printf("Array of String is = %s,%s,%s\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Note that you have an overflow in `arr[2]`, since "technologies" requires 13 characters. Your compiler should be warning you about this.

Comment: You're right. You know what's funny? I copied that example (http://roseindia.net/c-tutorials/c-array-string.shtml) and I added the `arr[0][0] = {"Douglas"};` part.

Comment: Use of `void main`  and `<conio.h>` in that example should ring very loud alarm bells, i.e. poor quality Indian college C code.

Comment: @PaulR: Actually, the compiler allows that *specific* case for character arrays, and omits the trailing NUL character. Of course, using such a string as if it were properly NUL-terminated is then undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Greg: interesting - I didn't know that - I wonder if you get a warning though...

Comment: Hmm - no warning with `gcc -Wall`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(arr[0], "Douglas");
```

When using `strcpy()`, you will have to ensure that there is enough space in the destination to hold the string you're putting there (plus the terminating NUL character). In this case there is, because you have allocated 12 bytes for each string and `"Douglas"` will take 8.